# PHP equivalent of VB.net character codes

Tags: php, vb.net, ascii

So I am calling an API written in VB.NET from PHP and passing it some text.  I want to insert into that text two linebreaks.

I understand that in VB.NET, the character codes for a linebreak are `Chr(10)` and `Chr(13)`.  How can I represent those in PHP?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [chr](http://php.net/chr) function exists in PHP too.

But, generally, we use "`\n`" (newline ; chr=10) and "`\r`" (carriage-return ; chr=13) *(note the double-quotes - do not use simple quotes here, is you want those characters)*

For more informations, and a list of the escape sequences for special characters, you can take a look at the [manual page about strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Answer (score 2):

- CR or Carriage Return, Chr(10), is represented by \r in a string
- LF or Line Feed, Chr(13), is represented by \n in a string

e.g.

```
echo "This is\r\na broken line";
```

this might look more familiar, using the PHP [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr) function, but you'd rarely see it done like this:

```
echo "This is".chr(10).chr(13)."a broken line";
```

There is also a constant called PHP_EOL which contains the [most appropriate line break sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) for the system PHP is running on.

Answer (score 0):

$break = "\n";